# Breaking a byte into parts

Tags: java, byte

I have a byte 00111101. I want to break it into two parts like 0011 1101 and create two new bytes 00000011 and 00001101. How can I do it in Java?

My code is:

```
byte b; //b has a particular value
byte result1= (b>>4) && 0x0f;
byte result2= b & 0x0f;
```

This code is giving me the following error:

```
cannot convert from int to byte.
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add a cast:

```
byte result1= (byte) ((b>>4) && 0x0f); 
byte result2= (byte) (b & 0x0f);
```

The results of arithmetic operations on integer types smaller than `int` are implicitly promoted to `int`, so you have to cast it back down to `byte`.

[JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) specifies this behavior as part of the binary numeric promotion rules:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Comment: when I am trying to cast it back to byte, it says "delete the token byte".

Comment: No, sorry my mistake. I was trying byte instead of (byte) while casting. Thanks for helping.